# showing new html codes using javascript and divstyles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a message page which shows your current messages. But the problem is that, it shows only one message, and that's the "newest" message. And the first messagebar which I click it, it won't show the HTML Code, even if it removes the "No mail Selected"

Here's how it sees if I press at second message tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmtTQ.png

My problem is that, the first messagetab it won't show it's HTML code. And when I change the message tabs (clicking new one) it won't actualise the new code. It shows the same code layout.

**I found that error is in javascript, at the MAILCONTENT (1 or 2), but i have no clue how to fix it**

JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.emailcontent input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    }
  });

  // Clicking a message
  $('.list-group-item > .media').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').removeClass('hide');
  });

 $('.list-group-item > .media2').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });



    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail2').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').removeClass('hide');
  });

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <div class="mainpanel">
    <div class="emailcontent">
      <div class="email-options">

        <label class="ckbox">
        </label>
      </div><!-- email-options -->
      <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item unread">
          <div class="list-left">
            <label class="ckbox">
            </label>
            </div>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
              <h5 class="media-heading">Sendername1</h5>
              <h5>Title1</h5>
            </div>
            <p>Hi. There's something wri..</p>
          </div>
        </div>

                <div class="list-group-item unread">
          <div class="list-left">
            <label class="ckbox">
            </label>
            </div>
          <div class="media2">
            <div class="media-left">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
              <h5 class="media-heading">Sendername2</h5>
              <h5>Title2</h5>
            </div>
            <p>That's title2 that means yo...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- emailcontent -->

 <div class="contentpanel emailpanel">
      <h3 class="nomail">No mail selected</h3>
      <div class="mailcontent hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            2 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Sendername1</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">MESSAGE1</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>Text1</p>


      </div><!-- mailcontent -->

    </div><!-- contentpanel --><!-- mailcontent -->
     <div class="contentpanel emailpanel">
      <h3 class="nomail">No mail selected</h3>
      <div class="mailcontent hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            2 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media2">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">Title2</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">MESSAGE2</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>That's message 2</p>

      </div><!-- mailcontent -->

    </div><!-- contentpanel --><!-- mailcontent -->
  </div><!-- mainpanel -->  
  </div><!-- mainpanel -->


    </div><!-- emailcontent -->
</div>
</div>
```

CODEPEN
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxGjWp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: may be you should redesign your code little bit.
But if you just want it working as it is, here is solution:

html:

```
  <div class="mainpanel">
    <div class="emailcontent">
      <div class="email-options">

        <label class="ckbox">
        </label>
      </div><!-- email-options -->
      <div class="list-group">
        <div class="list-group-item unread">
          <div class="list-left">
            <label class="ckbox">
            </label>
            </div>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
              <h5 class="media-heading">Sendername</h5>
              <h5>Title!</h5>
            </div>
            <p>This is messagebar1. Clicking it will show TITLE1.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

                <div class="list-group-item unread">
          <div class="list-left">
            <label class="ckbox">
            </label>
            </div>
          <div class="media2">
            <div class="media-left">
              <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <span class="pull-right">1 hour ago</span>
              <h5 class="media-heading">sendername2</h5>
              <h5>Title2</h5>
            </div>
            <p>This is messagebar2. Clicking it will show TITLE2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- emailcontent -->
 <div class="contentpanel emailpanel">
      <h3 class="nomail">No mail selected</h3>
      <div class="mailcontent hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            2 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media2">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">SENDER1</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">TITLE1</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>So this should be message1</p>
        </div>

        <br>
        <hr>

      </div><!-- mailcontent -->
   <div class="mailcontent2 hide">
        <div class="email-header">
          <div class="pull-right">
            2 hour ago &nbsp;


          </div>
          <div class="media2">
            <div class="media-left">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../images/photos/user1.png" alt="">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">sendername2</h4>
              to: me
            </div>
          </div><!-- media -->
        </div><!-- email-header -->

        <hr>

        <h3 class="email-subject">TITLE 2</h3>
        <div class="email-body">
          <p>So there is message2 layout. But if I click messagebar1 it won't show it's content and delete this or vice-versa</p>
        </div>

      </div><!-- mailcontent -->

  </div><!-- mainpanel -->  
  </div><!-- mainpanel -->
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.emailcontent input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.list-group-item').removeClass('selected');
    }
  });

  // Clicking a message
  $('.list-group-item > .media').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').removeClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent2').addClass('hide');
  });   

 $('.list-group-item > .media2').click(function() {

    $('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });



    $(this).parent().addClass('active').removeClass('unread');
    $('.nomail').addClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent2').removeClass('hide');
    $('.mailcontent').addClass('hide');
  });

});
```

So problem was that even when you hiding mailcontent2, its wrapper div is still visible and mailcontent is visible but under that empty div. I moved both mailcontent under same container div. I would suggest to you on load create an array of object that contains messages and assign to each left panel menu item id that is same as array index of that message, then you can have only one mailcontent and just assign different text to it from array.

Also use dev console in browser (usually F12) there you can hover over element and see its dimensions and location, so it was visible that second mail container is over the first one. Also there you can disable, enable and edit css fast and run javascript commands, so you can compose suitable style and see right away how it will look.

Comment: Ok. Officialy I love you. I usually use the F12, but this time nothing was changing. I stood yesterday late night to fix it but I couldn't. I will stay and study new script to see what's new and what I should learn. Thanks a lot.